# .htaccess redirect sitemap.xml to folder/custm_sitemap.xml

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I generate a sitemap xml file.

Because I have multiple websites pointed to the same directory, I stored into http://domain.com/domain.com/custom_websites.xml

How do I redirect `http://domain.com/sitemap.xml` TO `http://domain.com/domain.com/custom_websites.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(domain1)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ /%1.com/custom_websites.xml [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: Did you write requirement in opposite direction? You may want: `http://domain.com/domain.com/custom_websites.xml => http://domain.com/sitemap.xml`

Comment: But that is what you wrote you want in question.

Comment: Can I add a condition ... something like if HTTP_HOST = domain1.com to redirect to http://domain1.com/domain1.com/custom_websites.xml ???